# Port forwarding command

Tags: port-forwarding

I have a Linux machine which has 2 interfaces: for one of them (ip 1.1.1.1) I can access via ssh. For the other one (ip 2.2.2.2) I can't.
Some web application running on the second interface with port 12345.

I suppose that using port forwarding I can access to that application.

I'd be glad to have some assistance with the command for the port forwarding for this.

Comment: Do you intend the web app be public to everyone, or private to you only? Can you put up with always invoke ssh before accessing the webapp?

Comment: Also I assume your actual IP addresses are ones that IANA reserve for private networks, as 1.1.1.1 is a well-known IP address owned by CloudFlare.

Comment: @DannyNiu, any case, the network is private. provided IPs are for example

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ssh user@1.1.1.1 -L 12345:2.2.2.2:12345
```

Source: https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh (OpenSSH man pages)

Comment: on the local PC I should type http://localhost:12345 ?

Comment: @user1977050 yes, becaue the local address is not specified in -L option, it's assumed to be the anycast address